# Override PrimeNG component CSS

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

I am using PrimeNG OverlayPanel to be displayed in dropdown click but I have a problem to move default left arrow to right position. I tried everything that was in my mind but I am out of ideas.

Can you please give me some new idea for resolving this issue?

code example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-overlaypanel-demo

[dropdown arrow image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0Lpx.png)

Comment: Need some code example.

Comment: I just added it to main message (edited)

Comment: Your edit url is : https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-overlaypanel-demo

Comment: Thats generated by code... If its very important My suggestion is copy panel from source and customize that component.. But i did this before and not preferable way code is complex and too many inherited ts code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to style.css:

```
.p-overlaypanel:after, .p-overlaypanel:before{
  left: unset !important;
  right: 1.25rem !important;
  }
```

Now the arrow is on the right side opposite of initial.

Additional info: avoid using :host ::ng-deep as it is deprecated.. use the style.css file instead!

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

Your goal is override deeply incapsulated CSS. One of the possible sollution is to add an id to overlay-panel and then ovverride the desired element(in our case this is before and after pseudo-elements of a div with the p-overlay class

html:

```
<p-overlayPanel #op [showCloseIcon]="true" id='hello'[style]="{width: '450px'}">
```

css:

```
:host ::ng-deep #hello .p-overlaypanel::before,
    :host ::ng-deep #hello .p-overlaypanel::after
    {
      left: 80%;
    }
```

left: 80% is for example.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-overlaypanel-demo-fd9f6j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

Comment: Hm, very strange. I put id in my component and I put css like in your demo but it is not making any changes :O How is this possible?
I have only styles.css with all styles so there is no double css files or similar.

Comment: upvoted it - as including [style]="{width: '450px'} takes the changes effected

Answer (score 0):

```
.mybutton .p-overlaypanel:after, .mybutton .p-overlaypanel:before {
    bottom: 100%;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    right: 1.25rem; //<---
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
}
```

is the place but the question is;
how you wish to handle button positioning on page. If button near left,right,bottom border then you should handle arrow position. by this variable.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your entire Angular project to Scss. The reason is that View styles do not go deep. Scss in root does go deep and is worth it long term to stop using just CSS in Angular projects. I wrote an article on this.

Comment: https://dev.to/jwp/angular-10-ng-deep-and-host-pseudo-classes-1kbg

Answer (score 0):

For  p-overlaypanel
:before and :after are the attributes you should catch for this to work

```
 body .p-overlaypanel:before {
    left: calc(100% - 17px);
  }

  body .p-overlaypanel:after {

    left: calc(100% - 17px);
  }
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can override it in global stylesheet ie `style.scss`
by wrapping the elements with a custom class. This will provide more specificity.

```
.your-class {
  .p-overlaypanel:before {
    left: calc(100% - 17px);
  }

  .p-overlaypanel:after {
    left: calc(100% - 17px);
  }
}
```